# Are conditional targets in <transition> blocks supported in SCXML?

Tags: transition, scxml, apache-commons-scxml

I want to implement this sort of a *conditional transition* in SCXML:

```
current_state = s01  
if (Math.random() < 50) go to state s02  
  else go to state s03
```

Is this sort of conditional targets supported in SCXML ?
To put it into the SCXML language, is the equivalent of the following snippet possible ?

```
<transition event="event_1">
        <if cond="import java.util.Random; Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(100)) gt 50">
            <target="s02"/>
            <else/>
            <target="s03"/>
        </if>
</transition>
```

Would appreciate any pointers to their doc. for this / alternative strategies to handle it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following (untested) code will do what you want.

```
<scxml 
    datamodel="ecmascript"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml"
    version="1.0">

    <state id="s01">
      <transition event="event_1" target="s02" cond="Math.random() &gt; .5"/>
      <transition event="event_1" target="s03"/>
    </state> 

    <state id="s02"/>

    <state id="s03"/>

</scxml>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jbeard4. But my main motive is to know whether the "target" block can be taken out of the <transition> top level tag, and be put into any of the inner body statements like <if/>. Does SCXML allow that ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: No, SCXML (the standard) does not provide a mechanism for specifying the target anywhere other than the `<transition>` element attribute. For my company's SCXML implementation we have added a `targetexpr` attribute that evaluates code to decide the target.

Comment: But what we added is outside the standard, and not something supported by Apache SCXML, either. (And really, a non-deterministic state machine is a little weird.)

Comment: Phrogz: Having the 'target' expression within conditionals doesn't necessarily mean the State Machine will be non-deterministic. But I get your point.
@jbeard4: Imagine a scenario in experimentation which involves more than 5 paths from a node, each selected conditionally. While it is possible to solve it through data model / variables, it would be more intuitive to write conditionals inside the <transition>; mentioning targets against each condition, and a 'base' transition, if nothing matches. This would still make sure the SM is deterministic, but increase the flexibility in modelling.

Comment: @user1598865 I hope you see that what you describe is what jbeard4 shows in his answer. You can have the same event matched by many transitions, each with its own condition. The first transition (in document order) whose condition evaluates to true will be taken. This is thus similar to a `switch` statement.

Comment: If SCXML does not support this mechanism (which is essential for any non-trivial state machine: a transition is nearly always making decisions after several actions, and branch to a state or another depending on some intermediate results) is the only option to introduce an "artificial" intermediate state each time a transition contains a decision (`switch`) ?